# AD Directory Programming with Azure Active Directory

Tags: c#, .net, directoryservices, azure-active-directory

Is it possible to programmatically call Azure Active Directory using the System.DirectoryService namespace?

In essence, can I talk to the LDAP API provided in .NET against Azure's AD service.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Azure Active Directory does not support the LDAP protocol so you won't be able to use .NET's System.DirectoryService classes.  The AAD service uses something called the Graph API to query directory data.  This is a REST based web API.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh974476.aspx

If you want to do authentication via AAD you can use the ADAL library:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/jj573266.aspx